# Should a function be created only if I use it more than once?

Tags: php, function

Sometimes I have very large functions, that I feel are very difficult to "compress" or separate into smaller functions, because the functions wouldn't be used in any other part of the script.

So, I'd like some advice on it: should I create functions that wouldn't be used in other parts of the script, or should I create them only if they will be used more than once?

Thanks!

Summary:

- Fills arrays with info of files in directories.
- Processes TXT line by line, looks if the ID in TXT matches "Completed" files array and publishes it in an external product. If it doesn't, checks in the other arrays to make a report of what is missing.
- Saves
  the errors found in an array, then saves the array to an errors.txt
- file. Finally, returns the report.

Currently my function is:

```
protected function processScanned()
  {
    try
    {
      // EJECUTAR BASH DE NAHUEL
      //
      //
      $PdfCPList = $this->model->getDirFilenames( $this->model->dirCartasPorte, 'pdf' );
      $PdfTBList = $this->model->getDirFilenames( $this->model->dirTicketsBalanza, 'pdf' );
      $PdfCompList = $this->model->getDirFilenames( $this->model->dirCompletos, 'pdf' );
      $PdfUnreconList = $this->model->getDirFilenames( $this->model->dirSinReconocer,'pdf' );
      // Adjuntar Novedades
      $newsToProcess = $this->model->getDirFilenames( $this->model->dirNovedades, 'txt', true);
      $this->appendNewsFiles($newsToProcess);
      $report = array();
      $report['info'] = array(
        'Documentos procesados correctamente'=>0,
        'Fecha de última actualización de datos'=>date('d/m/Y H:i:s',(int)file_get_contents($this->model->uriTxtInfo)),
      );
      if($file = fopen( $this->model->uriTxtProcesar, 'r' ) )
      {
$i = 0;
        $errors_file = fopen($this->model->uriTxtErrores,'w');
        while( $line = fgets( $file ) )
        {
          if( ! preg_match( '/^\s/', $line ) )
            continue;

          $lineData = array(
            'id'=> substr($line,3,9),
            'prefix'=>'1234-' . $i,
            'suffix'=>'1234-' . $i,
            'partner'=>'FAZON TIMBUES OMHSA',
            'date'=>time() - 222,
          );
$i++;
          $keywordsToPublish = array(
            'Nº de Operacion'=>$lineData['id'],
            'Prefijo'=>$lineData['prefix'],
            'Sufijo'=>$lineData['suffix'],
            'Socio'=>$lineData['partner'],
            'Fecha'=>date('Y/d/m',$lineData['date']),
          );

          if( $this->model->findInDocusearch( $lineData['id'] ) )
          {
            continue;
          }

          if( array_key_exists( $lineData['id'], $PdfCompList ) )
          {
            $lineData['docName'] = 'Carta de Porte - Ticket de Balanza';
            $lineData['docId'] = 'CP-TB';
            $lineData['path'] = $this->model->dirCompletos . '/' . $lineData['id'] . '.pdf';
            if( $id = $this->model->publishInDocusearch( $lineData, $keywordsToPublish ) ) {
              $report['info']['Documentos procesados correctamente']++;
              link( $this->model->dirDocusearchRepo . '/' . $id . '.pdf', 
                $this->model->dirBackupCliente . '/' . $lineData['partner'] . '_' . date('Ymd',$lineData['date']) . '_' . $lineData['id'] . '.pdf'
              );
            }
            unset( $PdfCompList[ $lineData['id'] ] );
          }
          else
          {
            fwrite($errors_file, $line); // Guarda la fila leida en el archivo de errores.
            // Valores por defecto
            $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['date'] = $lineData['date'];
            $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['id'] = $lineData['id'];
            $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['type'] = 'nn';
            $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['actions'] = array();
            // Valores por defecto

            if( array_key_exists( $lineData['id'], $PdfCPList ) )
            {
              $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['reportMsg'] = 'Falta Ticket de Balanza.';
              $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['type'] = 'cp';
              unset( $PdfCPList[ $lineData['id'] ] );
            }
            elseif( array_key_exists( $lineData['id'], $PdfTBList ) )
            {
              $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['reportMsg'] = 'Falta Carta de Porte.';
              $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['type'] = 'tb';
              unset( $PdfTBList[ $lineData['id'] ] );
            }
            else
            {
              $report[ 'errors' ][ $lineData['id'] ]['reportMsg'] = 'Ningún archivo digitalizado.';
            }
          }
        }

        fclose( $file );
        fclose( $errors_file );
        $this->fileRename( $this->model->uriTxtErrores, $this->model->uriTxtProcesar);
        foreach( $PdfCompList as $key=>$value )
        {
          $report[ 'errors' ][ $key ] = array( 
            'reportMsg'=>'Falta en archivo de datos del sistema externo.',
            'date'=>$value['date'],
            'id'=>$key,
            'type'=>'co',
            'actions'=>array('get','rename','delete'),
          );
        }
        foreach( $PdfCPList as $key=>$value )
        {
          $report[ 'errors' ][ $key ] = array(
            'reportMsg'=>'Carta de Porte no utilizada.',
            'date'=>$value['date'],
            'id'=>$key,
            'type'=>'cp',
            'actions'=>array('get','rename','delete'),
          );
        }
        foreach( $PdfTBList as $key=>$value )
        {
          $report[ 'errors' ][ $key ] = array(
            'reportMsg'=>'Ticket de Balanza no utilizado.',
            'date'=>$value['date'],
            'id'=>$key,
            'type'=>'tb',
            'actions'=>array('get','rename','delete'),
          );
        }
        foreach( $PdfUnreconList as $key=>$value )
        {
          $report[ 'errors' ][ $key ] = array(
            'reportMsg'=>'Documento no reconocido.',
            'date'=>$value['date'],
            'id'=>$key,
            'type'=>'un',
            'actions'=>array('get','rename','delete'),
          );
        }
        return $report;
      }
      else
      {
        throw new Exception('No se pudo abrir el archivo TXT');
      }
    }
    catch( Exception $e )
    {
      $this->mensaje = $e->getMessage();
      header('HTTP/1.1 500 ' . $this->mensaje);
    }
 }
```

Comment: primarily opinion based: Do it only if it helps to give you more overview

Comment: You should let the lack of guru words on the matter stop you, if you can divide your function into logical parts and it makes it easier for you, then why not?

Comment: Large function are good candidates to break into smaller ones. Ideally a function doesn't have more then a few lines of code in the body.

Comment: Crap.. was going to give a pretty decent answer but closed :c

Comment: @Jonast92 put on hold, that means it can be reopen if Jorge is more specific. Is he worried about a particual metric? Is he looking for some design pattern? Anything that give a clear criteria of what is a good answer so it is not just throwing opinions.

Comment: @Theraot Yes you are right, I just don't know how to reformulate my question...

Comment: @Jorge So you are unsure about rewriting your questions and you are unsure about rewriting your functions... maybe you just need a nap :P

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question. It's fine to have a function even if only used once. Blocks of code should ideally only do one thing, perform one computation, one calculation. This makes it easy to work on the flow of your logic, instead of getting bogged down with huge blocks of code. Have a look at SOLID principles: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design) Voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree with MrCode, functions should never do more than one thing and should also be named like that one thing! so if you got a huge function it is likely to do more than one thing ;) divide it into smaller bits... ;) I think this question is pretty everydaylike though and should be answered by different opinions, isn't that about learning too; listening to other telling their opinion and experience?

Comment: Thanks @MrCode, I've put the code that made me post this question... The 'report' part is the one that's bigger and is disturbing me but due to it's nature I don't know if it would be a good idea to move to a function, because It will occuppy almost the same space.

Comment: @Jorge I think there's room to separate it out yes, there seems to be a few different things going on. If you have functions that do specific things, it's easy to see the flow of logic. When you have a huge wall of code, this is usually a sign it can be separated out. Maybe separate out the file i/o stuff too.

Comment: @Jorge You still need to mark an answer as correct :) I'm guessing you'll go for the +9 answer, but mine is more in-depth. Regardless, you need to 'tick' one =]

Comment: @Jorge Yes the method is too large. Also you don't need to warp the body inside try / catch. Instead wrap the call to the method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**This is totally up to you.**

However,
Separating code blocks into different functions can make the code more readable (when it's not done too excessively). Functions are not only meant for repeated use of code, they're also intended to make the code more orginized and easier to understand. You might get lost if you try to read through a long function that does a lot of tasks in parallel however if you take this function and break some parts of it into smaller functions with proper naming the function will be much shorter and clearer for you to maintain in the future or for the next programmer working on your project to understand what you've done.

Also, a good practice will be to create **objects** that will deal with certain more-specific tasks. This will allow (among many other benefits) to update the code by extending the classes without having to harm the original functionality.

As per your edit, a good way to determine whether or not you should split you function to pieces is found in the "function summary" you've written. When you have more than 1-2 tasks it will be a good idea to break into separate functions. I recommend writing a function for each of the following:

- Fill arrays with info of files in directories
- Processes TXT line by line, looks if the ID in TXT matches
  "Completed" files array
- Publish array in an external product
- Check in the other arrays to make a report of what is missing.
- Saves the errors found in an array, then saves the array to an
  errors.txt
- Ofcourse the function that wraps everything together and when done, returns the report.

Comment: It would also be possible to create static classes (i.e. classes which only contain static helper functions).

Comment: Static functions are **bad**, try testing proper OOP code with a load of statics in there.

Answer (score 2):

In SOLID, you should take a look at the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

> In object-oriented programming, the single responsibility principle states that every class should have a single responsibility, and that responsibility should be entirely encapsulated by the class. All its services should be narrowly aligned with that responsibility.

You can also apply this to individual functions - each one should be readable and perform the main task for which is was created.

You also seem like you're talking about *anonymous functions* - one off throwaways.

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
$greet = function($name)
{
    printf("Hello %s\r\n", $name);
};
```

You can see how `$greet` has a function return it's value.

If you're using this function multiple times in your code however, make it a *real* function that you can call multiple times as  you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Naming functions is hard. So whenever you see a block of code with an obvious name then you should give it that name. Separating concerns is hard. So whenever you see two obviously separate concerns you should keep them clearly separate. Reordering operations is hard. So when you see two operations that can obviously be reordered then you should make them easy to reorder. Of course it makes sense to write functions that may only be used once.